# How can I make sure that my headers are always centered both full width and responsively?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a header in a fixed width column using Twitter Bootstrap 3. From a *proper* design perspective, what is the best way to make sure that it is centered both in full screen width and when it is minimized responsively?

```css
.firstheader {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Prosto One', cursive;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="content col-md-8">
    <h1 class="firstheader"> Header Goes Here! </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7p5Bw

Comment: Thanks! @isherwood Could you explain the logic behind this hack?

Comment: You're welcome, but it's in no sense a hack. Have you looked at the grid docs for Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting